# Creating "shortcut" to manipulate deeply nested object keys

Tags: javascript

I have a deeply nested object, and throughout my code I often need to manipulate data like this:

```
var current_index = test_dict['current']['index']
var current_section = test_dict['current']['section']
test_dict[current_section]['data']['words'][current_index]
```

So you can see when accessing the object, I'm using variables that reference other parts of the object. This has been working great for me, but throughout my code I also need to periodically update current_index and current_section.

Since those variables are only shallow copies/references and not direct shortcuts to those actual values, doing current_index++ increases current_index but not test_dict['current']['index']

In my code test_dict needs to store all of the current information, so I'm trying to figure out how I can update that dictionary directly without typing out a deeply nested path.

I know I can use dot notation, but that wouldn't save me any time since I would have to do something like:

```
test_dict[test_dict.current.section]['data']['words'][test_dict.current.index]
```

I know I can also create a reference to let current_index and let current_section at the beginning of the function, but since I have to manipulate that test_dict object in almost every function it would be impractical to define it hundreds of times.

Is there a better way? Should I just create a getCurrentIndex() function and then do this?

```
test_dict[getCurrentSection()]['data']['words'][getCurrentIndex()]
```

Comment: You can do `let current = test_dict.current`, and then you can use `current.index` or `current.section`.

Comment: @Barmar as I said in my post, I know I can do dot notation but was looking for a better way. I described the reason why in detail.

Comment: It's shorter because you can leave out `test_dict`.

Comment: `getCurrentIndex()` is longer than `current.index`

Comment: @Barmar I was giving an example of my object structure. In reality it's about 10-15 layers deep, and I was asking if I should resort to using a function to get the value if there's no other option.

Comment: @TheNomadicAspie There is another option - the one that Barmar presented. To keep the reference, you need only the last layer; use the object property `current.index` instead of the number variable `current_index`. (In the example, it's even the same number of characters)

Comment: Unless you have variable indexes along the way, you can set a variable to everything but the last property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since those variables are only shallow copies/references and not direct shortcuts to those actual values, doing current_index++ increases current_index but not test_dict['current']['index']

OK.. objects(and arrays) are pointers/references.. numbers, strings, booleans, etc are copies.. If you want shortcuts to things, here is an example

```js
var current=test_dict['current'];
var current_index = current['index'];
var current_section = current['section'];
test_dict[current_section]['data']['words'][current_index];
current['index']++ //index inside test_dict would get added to
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try [`Proxy object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
const dict = {
  current: {
    index: 1,
    section: "test1"
  },
  test1: {
    data: {
      words: ["test1 index0", "test1 index1", "test1 index2"]
    }
  },
  test2: {
    data: {
      words: ["test2 index0", "test2 index1", "test2 index2"],
      other: {
        sub1: {
          sub1_1: ["some", "text", "blah"],
          sub1_2: "single string",
          sub1_3: {}
        }
      }
    },
    blah: {
      sub1: {
        sub1_4: 123456
      }
    }
  }
}

const test_dict = new Proxy(dict, {
  get: function (target, key, receiver)
  {
    const data = target[dict.current.section] && target[dict.current.section][key] || target[key];
    if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null && !(data instanceof Array))
      return new Proxy(data, this)

    return data instanceof Array && data[dict.current.index] || data || target;
  }
});
console.log("[data][words]", test_dict['data']['words']);
test_dict.current.index = 2
console.log("[data][words]", test_dict['data']['words']);
test_dict.current.section = "test2"
test_dict.current.index = 0
console.log("[data][words]", test_dict['data']['words']);

console.log("data.words", test_dict.data.words);
console.log("data", test_dict.data);
console.log("sub1", test_dict['data']['other']['sub1']);
console.log("sub1_1", test_dict['data']['other']['sub1']['sub1_1']);
console.log("sub1_2", test_dict['data']['other']['sub1']['sub1_2']);
console.log("sub1_3", test_dict['data']['other']['sub1']['sub1_3']);
console.log("blah.sub1_4", test_dict['blah']['sub1']['sub1_4']);
```